# Is the function is differentiable at 0?

Tags: real-analysis

Is  the function given by

$ f(x)  = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x \log2} - \frac{1}{2^x-1},\text{if} \  x\neq 0 ,\\\frac{ 1}{2} \ \text   {if} \  x=0 \end{cases}$.

is differentiable at zero ?

## My Attempts:

## $f'(0) =  \frac{f(x) -  f(0)}{x-0} =\frac{\frac{1}{x \log2} - \frac{1}{2^x-1}- \frac{1}{2} }{x} $

after that i can not able to proceed further

Pliz  help me

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: A Limit is missing!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner.....ya  i misses that

Comment: Make those denominators of fractions involving $x$ over the line be the same. If you have learned the Maclaurin formula then you can applied it and asymptotically transform the numerator to polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac1{2^x-1}=\frac1{\exp(x\ln2)-1}=\frac1{x\ln 2+x^2(\ln 2)^2/2+O(x^3)}
=\frac1{x\ln 2}\left(1-\frac{\ln 2}2+O(x)\right)$$
etc.